# Undo changes in git since the last push?

Tags: git

Newbie question: How do I undo local changes in a git repo back to the last push? I see lots of guidance for rolling back the last commit, or all local changes, but not this case specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You find the commit to which you want to go back (let's say `foo`) and then say `git reset --hard foo`. The next push you do should be a force push if you want it to go through though.

Comment: And is foo the longish hash label for the commit?

Comment: It can be any [treeish](http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html) one of which is the full or partial hash.

Comment: Okay, I've found the documentation. Reset will trash changes, right?  If I wanted to save the changes in the repo, but get rid of them in the current head, I'd use revert, correct?

Comment: It depends on the kind of reset you use. A hard reset trashes the changes. I've put a link to some nice documentation in my answer. Please read it, and you will discover the powers of git.

Comment: `revert` will add another commit that applies a reverse patch. In other words, you "undo" a commit by applying the diff in reverse. `reset` allows you to move a reference to any point in the DAG. You should really go through the docs. Git is very hard to understand if you try to blindly map from "command" to "action". Once you understand the innards, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: By the way, to preserve your changes you can also use the git reset command, without the --hard. If you type man git-reset, you will get an overview of the different types of reset that you can do.

Answer (score 3):

Quick&Dirty way: Delete the local branch and create it from the remote one again

```
git checkout anotherBranch
git branch -D branchA
git checkout -b branchA origin/branchA
```

Comment: This indeed is a dirty way. You're not teaching him how to fix stuff this way. Using git reset hard you can go back to any commit. Even to a commit that has not been pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Pushed it that means it will stay in history forever.

Now - Assuming your push is latest on that branch you can..

```
git revert 
git push origin master #assuming you on master branch
```

If this is not latest commit - 
you can choose

git rebase --interactive 
and remove specific change set

Answer (score 0):

You can do a git reset hard for that. See man git-reset.

In the git log find the hash of the commit you want to go back to. All changes after that commit are undone.

By the way [here](http://progit.org/book/) you will find an excellent book for learning about git.